# Using arbitrary/different Backbone models in a view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

Can one use differently defined models defined via require.js/AMD in a single central view? I mean separately defined models, not ones of a collection.

If yes, how they are referenced in the json part of the callback function of `define()` that defines that central view, in its vars, in functions of its attributes etc. There can only one `this.model`, right?

Is it possible to Render different templates, possibly populated by vars from those different models, conditionally, from within this single central view?

To extend my question:

Can one use differently defined collections defined via require.js/AMD in a single central view?

Can one use differently defined models defined via require.js/AMD in a single collection? (this alone could achieve first goal with referencing only this capable collection.)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Please provide an exemple.

Comment: That's a lot of questions in one question :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Can one use differently defined models defined via require.js/AMD in a
>   single central view? I mean separately defined models, not ones of a
>   collection.
>
> If yes, how they are referenced in the json part of the callback
>   function of define() that defines that central view, in its vars, in
>   functions of its attributes etc. There can only one this.model, right?

A `View`'s `this.model` is just one way to provide a view with a model.  You can also pass whatever other options you want to a view, like so:

```
var YourView = Backbone.View.exend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.foo = options.foo;
    }
});
var modelA = new Backbone.Model();
var modelB = new Backbone.Model();
var yourView = new YourView({model: modelA, foo: modelB});
// yourView.model == modelA
// yourView.foo == modelB
```

> Is it possible to Render different templates, possibly populated by
>   vars from those different models, conditionally, from within this
>   single central view?

Yup.  For instance, here's an example if we add a render method to `YourView`:

```
render: function() {
    if (this.model.get('bar')) {
        this.$el.html(this.templateA(this.model.toJSON());
    } else {
        this.$el.html(this.templateB(this.foo.toJSON());
    }
}
```

> Can one use differently defined collections defined via require.js/AMD
>   in a single central view?
>   Yup, the same way as you pass in multiple models.  It doesn't matter if you use Require; you can pass around Backbone objects/classes through it just fine.
>
> Can one use differently defined models defined via require.js/AMD in a
>   single collection? (this alone could achieve first goal with
>   referencing only this capable collection.)
>   Yup, just throw all the models in to a single collection, like so:

```
var modelA = new ModelClass();
var modelB = new SomeOtherModelClass();
var collection = new Backbone.Collection([modelA, modelB]);
```

The only limit is that a `Collection` can only have a single `model` property, which means that whenever you create a new `Model` through the `Collection` (eg. via `fetch` or `create`) they will all be of that model.

(It's possible to get around even that with if you replace the `model` with a custom function, but you shouldn't need to do that.)